# HTML5 video limit in FireFox?

Tags: html, html5-video

Seems as though FF will only let me have 24 active videos on a page at once, which is one shy of what I want! Any thoughts?
http://graysonearle.com/bluemen/

```
<div id="container">
<script type="text/javascript">
    for (var i=0;i< vid_count;i++) {
        document.write('<div class="vidBox" id="box'+i+'">');
        document.write('    <video class="vid" loop="loop" preload="auto" id="vid'+i+'">');
        document.write('        <source src="videos/0.mp4?a='+i+'" type="video/mp4">');
        document.write('        <source src="videos/0.webm" type="video/webm">');
        document.write('    </video>');
        document.write('</div>');
    }

var videos = document.getElementsByTagName('video');

for(var i = 0, ii = videos.length; i < ii; i++) {
    videos[i].addEventListener('canplaythrough',enablePlayback,false);
}

var videosLoaded = 0;

function enablePlayback(e) {
    videosLoaded++;
    if(videosLoaded == vid_count) {
        // enable a play button or do whatever you want
        // in this case: start playing all the videos at once
        for(var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
            //alert(i);
            videos[i].play();
        }
    }
}
</script>
</div>
```

If I manually videos[24].play() after that, vid 23 won't play, and so on. This leads me to believe I'm running into a hard limit on the number of videos allowed.

EDIT: I just left my browser open for a bit and realized that maybe 3-5 minutes into the page sitting there, the 25th video started playing, though there was some serious de-syncing.